# What is KIRCHSTRASSE on my statement bill?

Tags: online-banking, receipt, transaction

I'm from the UK, I've been in Spain for few days and I've checked my bank statement recently, and I'm have the following transaction which I can't recognise:

```
4 Sep 2014  POS 0158 02SEP14 , KIRCHSTRASSE , 6####SCHA , . LI , EUR 23.54, VRATE 1.2507, FGN PUR FEE 1.00  -   19.82
```

Googling it points me to some Switzerland and German websites where I haven't been there for a while.

How I can check who (which company) charged me for the above transaction?

Comment: Since you've found out for yourself, try finding a better title for the question: it's wayy to specific as it is since "Kirchstrasse" is just the name of a street as part of an address.

Comment: I didn't find completely yet what's the company name. Actually bank said that the POS could be also on-line transaction. I think that specific title would help other people identify that kind of transaction by Googling it.

Comment: The problem is that it's way too specific (to one store address rather than to a kind of transaction).

Comment: After investigation, I don't think it's too specific, as it was used by MultiCards global on-line cashier service. And that kind of statements only really confuse people and I believe the following Q&A will help people with their statement issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

POS stands for [Point of Sale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_sale) (like a specific store location) which indicates that the purchase occurred by using your debit card, but it can also be the on-line transaction done via [3-D Secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-D_Secure).

Checking with bank, they said that Kirchstrasse transaction could be related to direct marketing subscription service ordered on-line.

Investigating further what I've found these kind of transactions are performed by [2BuySafe](https://www.2buysafe.com/) company registered at Kirchstrasse in Liechtenstein with went through the [MultiCards](https://www.multicards.com/) on-line cashier which can be used for paying different variety of services (e.g. in this case it was polish on-line storage service called [Chomikuj](http://www.chomikuj.pl)).

These kind of transactions can be tracked by checking the e-mail (e.g. in gmail by the following query: `after:2014/09/02 before:2014/09/02 Order`).

Remember, that if you still don't recognise your transaction, you should call your bank.

---

I have found also some other people concerns about that kind of transactions who ask: [Is 2BuySafe.com and www.multicards.com some sort of Scam?](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140105091322AAPmuQR)

Provided answer says:

> MultiCards Internet Billing is a provider of online credit card and
>   debit card processing and payment solutions to many retailers
>   worldwide. MultiCards was one of the pioneer companies offering this
>   type of service since 1995 and is a PCI / DSS certified Internet
>   Payment Service Provider (IPSP) providing service to hundreds of
>   retail websites worldwide  MultiCards is a registered Internet Payment
>   Service Provider and has implemented various fraud protection tools
>   including, but not limited to, MultiCards Fraud Score Tool and
>   'Verified by Visa' and 'MasterCard SecureCode' to protect card
>   holder's card details.  2BuySafe.com Is also Secured and Verified By
>   GeoTrust  The certificate should be trusted by all major web browsers
>   (all the correct intermediate certificates are installed).
>
> The certificate was issued by GeoTrust.
>
> Entering Incorrect information can lead to a card being rejected as @
>   TOS  2BuySafe.com is hosted on the Multicards Server site